# Use rails github_api to upload csv file to github repo

Tags: ruby-on-rails, github, upload

Is there a way to upload csv file from UI and rails will upload it to github repo either with or without github_api?

Answer (score 0):

If your application can support installing/declaring **[octokit](https://github.com/octokit/octokit.rb)** (as [in here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/70431752/6309)), you can use that library for your GitHub goals:

```
client = Octokit::Client.new(:access_token => "YOUR_GITHUB_TOKEN")
```

Or:

```rb
client = Octokit::Client.new(
    client_id: ENV['GITHUB_CLIENT_ID'],
    client_secret: ENV['GITHUB_CLIENT_SECRET'],
)
client.user(ENV['GITHUB_CLIENT_ID'], :headers => { "X-GitHub-OTP" => "2fa-token"})
```

Then, using [`create_contents`](https://octokit.github.io/octokit.rb/Octokit/Client/Contents.html#create_contents-instance_method):

```rb
client.create_contents("username/repositoryName", "branchName", "path/to/yourFile.csv", "file...content")
```